# How to disable buttons after x amount of clicks in js?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I am trying to use Javascript to disable a button after it is clicked x amount of times.  For simplicity sake lets say x = 2 for now. I cannot seem to get the counter to increment.  Thank You for any help!

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

window.onload = function () {
    coke.onclick = function(){
        var count =0;
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            coke.disabled = true;
        }
        else
            count++;
    };
}
```

Where "coke" is the element ID.  If i get rid of the `if` statement and just have `coke.disabled = true`, of course it works and disables after one click.  I'm sure there is a core concept I am missing.
Thank You

Comment: To get a working dollarsign, just add jQuery !

Comment: Don't you want `$("coke").onclick = function () { };` then?

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because each time the `onclick` event is fired, your `var count` is being assigned to 0, so it will never be greater than or equal to one in your function. If you initialize the `count` var outside of the `onclick` function, it will behave as expected.

```
window.onload = function () {
   var count = 0;
   coke.onclick = function(){
       if (count >= 1)
       {
           coke.disabled = true;
       }
       else
           count++;
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `count` outside the scope of your `onclick` function:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var count = 0;    // set initial count to 0
window.onload = function () {
    coke.onclick = function(){
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            coke.disabled = true;
        }
        else
            count++;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let count =0;

let add = document.getElementById('btn-add');
let sub = document.getElementById('btn-sub');
let counter = document.getElementById('div-cls');

add.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   
    if (count >= 10) {
        add.disabled = true;
    } else {
        count++;
    }

    counter.innerHTML = count;
})
sub.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(count <=-10){
        sub.disabled=true;
    }
    else{
        count--;
    }
    
    counter.innerHTML = count;
})

console.log(counter);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <button id="btn-add">Add</button>
    <div id="div-cls">0</div>
    <button id="btn-sub">Subtract</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).